# Mongod service is on systemd list but failed to get properties

Tags: services, systemd

I'm using Ubuntu 16.
Mongodb service is on the list when I try running `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`

[image: here]

but when I try running `systemctl start mongodb` it says 
`Failed to start mongodb.service: Unknown unit: mongodb.service`

Running `systemctl status  mongodb.service` outputting `Failed to get properties: No such interface ''`

here is the `mongodb.service` unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you installed MongoDB and where you installed it from, the package might have been named 'mongod' or 'mongodb'. Apparently, you've installed it under both names. I suspect your problem stems from the duplicate packages.

First, check which MongoDB packages you have actually installed:

```
dpkg -l '*mongod*' | grep ii
```

Then, for each 'server' package installed, check which /etc/ "init" or "service" files belong to the package actually have installed. In my case, I have `mongodb-org-server` installed on 16.04, and my result looks like this:

```
$ dpkg -L   mongodb-org-server  | grep systemd
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

If you have another file in "/etc/init" for "/etc/systemd" that is *not* related to the version of MongoDB you actually have installed, remove it. You probably used "apt-get remove" on an old package, which doesn't automatically *purge* files in /etc.

If you've added or removed systemd `.service` files, use `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to make sure your changes are reflected.

Comment: In my case, only `mongodb-org-server` yields a result, it's the same as yours. Then what am I going to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when run `systemctl start mongodb` and `systemctl status  mongodb.service`. In my case Ubuntu was updated to 16.04 from 14.04 and uses upstart-sysv instead of systemd-sysv. For this reason, all of the `systemctl` commands were not working.

If your system uses upstart-sysv you need to install MongoDB for Ubuntu 14.04 and don't need to create any mongodb.service configs. Just run mongodb with command:

```
service mongod start
```

It helped me, hope it will help someone else.